# Transactions blocked when Managed Package expired

Tags: managed-package

When a managed package license expired, all updates that invoked that package's metadata failed.

Is this because the specific package was designed poorly, or does Salesforce simply fail transactions that call namespaces with expired licenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter. Salesforce doesn't allow access to a package without a license. The only thing you'd be able to do is uninstall the package or renew the licenses.

Comment: Thank you. This is disappointing that there's no explicit warning about license expiration blocking transactions.